# R shiny ggplot with if conditions multiple layers

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, shiny

I am creating a shiny app with the following goal in my mind.

1. Select studyid and then plot mean on y and avisit on x-axis.
2. After that if the user selects the subjects from list of subjects , I should be able to super impose scatter plot and a line plot.

I am using the following code , it works fine but i am not able to add another layer in the if block to draw a line plot.Any help

```
if (input$studyid == "xxx") {
  ggplot(list_val_mean[[1]],aes(AVISIT,mean))  +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() + {
      if (length(input$subjlist) > 0) geom_point(data = filt_df[[1]] %>% 
                                                   filter(SUBJID %in% input$subjlist), aes(AVISIT,VAL))
      
    } +
    theme_classic()
}
```

Thank

Comment: Try with a list, i.e. `if(...) list(geom_point(...), geom_line(...))`

Comment: Thanks. it worked.